# Not able to send multiple messages to TCP Listener from one TCP port

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, listener

I want to send 5 messages from port 7021 to listener of port 7022.

This means that single client send multiple messages to listener.

Following is the implementation:

```
                        string message = "787814014E612096";
    
                        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.126"), 7021);
                        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.126"), 7022);
    
                        // Create a TCP/IP socket.    
                        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    
                        sender.Bind(endpoint);
                        sender.Connect(remoteEP);
    
                        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    
                        int index = 1;
                        while (index < 6)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Send packet: " + index);
                              
                            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
    
                            Thread.Sleep(2000);
                            
                            index = index + 1;
                        }
    
                        // Release the socket.    
                        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        sender.Close();
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have an application(framing) protocol. Streaming sockets deal in streams, not messages. You need to separate your messages by something other than time. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, your ans is not clear.

Comment: There's no guarantee that one call to `Send` at one end will be matched to a single call of `Receive` at the other. TCP is an endless stream of bytes, so if you've called `Send` 5 times with 16 bytes each time, the listener *might* receive all 80 bytes in one call. Or it's first call could e.g. return just 4 bytes, the next could return 16 bytes (12 from the first send, 4 from the second), etc. If you want *messages*, it's up to *you* to implement them atop this endless stream of bytes (or switch to a higher level protocol that implements messages for you)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but how we can send 5 times, by using the implementation I shared?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol. You could use a message-based protocol like UDP or SCTP.

Answer (score 0):

Some key points:

1. Use TcpClient and TcpListener instead of sockets.
2. Use the Task Async Pattern instead of Async callbacks.
3. Use the OS to allocate a source port instead of allocating one manually.
4. Use Task.Delay() instead of Thread.Sleep();

The following line, ***asks*** the operating system to send the data.

```
int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);
```

However, you have no way of guaranteeing that the OS will send the data immediately, it can, and sometimes will hang on to that data and send it later.

You also need to be checking bytesSent to find out how many bytes were placed in the outbound queue.

Using `TcpClient` and the `NetworkStream` that comes with `TcpClient` will alleviate a lot of the Socket edge cases that you will encounter.